# Insert a string on line after a match ignoring lines with a #

Tags: bash, awk, sed, printf

This may prove to be a difficult one.

I need a way of adding an alias to an Apache2 configuration file via a bash script.

I have already conquered checking if the alias is already in use in another configuration file with grep. The problem I face now is how to add 'ServerAlias testing.com' to the configuration file.

Each configuration file has two virtual hosts for port 80 and port 443.

I need to add the string 'ServerAlias testing.com' to each configuration on the next line after 'ServerName' but ignoring any lines beginning with a # or ;.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # A comment with ServerName in it <-- must be ignored

    ServerName test.com
    <<ADD STRING HERE>> 

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName test.com
    <<AND HERE>>

</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
Comments have to ignored as the default configurations on apache have comments that I wish to leave in place and in those comments is 'ServerName' which must be ignored, there will only ever be one 'ServerName' per virtual host.

The virtual host tags do not matter to me as long as I can ignore the comments and add the `ServerAlias testing.com` once on the line after `ServerName` in each virtual host configuration.

THIS NEEDS TO MAKE THE EDITS TO THE CONFIGURATIONS AND THEN SAVE TO FILE

Comment: What do you really want to add, `ServerAlias testing.com` or `ServerName 'test.com'` ? You are talking about the both (mind the quotes as well).

Comment: All sorted now :-) Need to add `ServerAlias testing.com`

Comment: so my next question to you will be you want to skip whole block if any comment comes or you don't want to print that comment? Could you please more specific into your question?

Comment: If `ServerName` can appear anywhere else in your file that you do **NOT** want it changed then include those cases in your sample input/output. Finding a target string in a file is trivial, including/excluding that same target string in various contexts is where things get more interesting. Right now you have different people making different assumptions about whether the `VirtualHost` text is relevant and, if so, in what way so clear up all the confusion by stating if they are or are not part of your requirements for finding ServerName and include relevant examples in your sample input/output

Comment: Also is the fact that your new string includes "testing.com" in any way related to the existing string including "test.com"?

Comment: OK, you've added `there will only ever be one 'ServerName' per virtual host.` so it's getting better but now state whether or not `ServerName` can occur uncommented in contexts other than inside a virtual host block and, if so, how you want it handled. Also clarify or remove the `between two strings` part of your question title.

Comment: @Ed Morton I think the `VirtualHost` tag would be irrelevant, just need to add an alias once to each configuration ignoring any line beginning with # or  ; and yes sometimes the comments include `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`

Comment: I see you now added `THIS NEEDS TO MAKE THE EDITS TO THE CONFIGURATIONS AND THEN SAVE TO FILE` . Why can't you just do `command file > tmp && mv tmp file`?

Comment: @Dan you started saying `"This may prove to be a difficult one"`. But after all the updates to your question, it seems like all you need to do is adding a line after the one that matches a pre-defined pattern? [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding asking a good question.

Answer (score 0):

try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/<\/VirtualHost>/{a=""} /VirtualHost/{a=1} a && $1~/ServerName/ && $2 ~ /test.com/{print $0 RS "    ServerAlias " s1 "testing.com" s1;next} 1 ' s1="'"  Input_file
```

**EDIT1:** As OP want to ignore comments and save it into Input_file itself so try following.

```
awk '/^#/{next} /<\/VirtualHost>/{a=""} /VirtualHost/{a=1} a && $1~/ServerName/ && $2 ~ /test.com/{print $0 RS "    ServerAlias " s1 "testing.com" s1;next} 1 ' s1="'"  Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Comment: Here, insertion can happen outside a `<VirtualHost>...</VirtualHost>` block as well.

Comment: @Anubis, edited the code  now accordingly, thank you.

Comment: @Anubis the OP hasn't suggested that that would be a problem. He probably simply doesn't have any `ServerName test.com` anywhere in his file except where he wants to make the change.

Comment: @EdMorton As I understand, he is trying to imply that with `"...Each configuration file has two virtual hosts for port 80 and port 443..."`

Comment: @Anubis Hopefully he'd have included in his example a case where he doesn't want to add the new string after the target string if such a case could exist in his input but I guess we'll see what the OP has to say...

Comment: Hi this answer does not ignore the lines with comments and focuses on the server name being test.com but that will change for each virtualhost I configure.

Comment: @Dan you said `I need to add ... after 'ServerName test.com'`. If that's not true then edit your question to state your real requirement.

Comment: So where the comments will come on VirtualHost or somewhere else, kindly do edit the post with same details.

Comment: @Anubis the OP just updated the question to say the virtualhost stuff is irrelevant.

Comment: @Dan, please try now and let me know then if this helps, it will ignore all the comments.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, I think all the answerers have understood his requirement in completely different ways. I've tried to provide a perfect answer reading his entire description. I believe providing a complete answer, instead of giving a quick fix to address only this specific case, will help someone in future who come here with a related but different requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/<VirtualHost \*:\(80\|443\)>/{
    :a;
    n;
    /<\/VirtualHost>/!{
        /^\(\s*#.*\|\s*\)$/ba;
        s/\(\s*\)ServerName test.com/&\n\1ServerAlias testing.com/;
        ba; 
    };
}' <input_file_path
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{print} /^[[:space:]]*ServerName/{sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"ServerAlias testing.com"); print}' file
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # A comment with ServerName in it <-- must be ignored

    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias testing.com

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias testing.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Note that it indents the new string using whatever indentation existed on the preceding line.

Comment: Does this ignore lines beginning with a # as it may end up adding the `ServerAlias testing.com` on the line after the comment aswell

Comment: Scrap that I now see you are only selecting lines that have white space before them

Comment: How to output this to a file

Comment: Just like saving the output of any command to a file, add `> outputfile` to the end of the command line. And if you want to change the original file then with any given command (awk, sed, grep, whatever) you just do `command file > tmp && mv tmp file` so in this case `awk '...script...' file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Answer (score 0):

Another ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '/^ *ServerName test.com/{s=substr($0,1,index($0,"S")-1)"ServerAlias testing.com"; 
     printf "%s\n%s\n", $0,s; next }1' file
```

The output:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # A comment with ServerName in it <-- must be ignored

    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias testing.com

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias testing.com

</VirtualHost>
```

---

Additional ***sed*** approach:

```
sed -i 's/^\( *\)\(ServerName test.com\)/\1\2\n\1ServerAlias testing.com/' file
```

Comment: How to output this to a file

Comment: @Dan, use my second approach to modify the file in-place